# cfprint and cfdocument resource from a database runs slow

Tags: performance, coldfusion, cfdocument, cfprint

I have been having issues printing a `cfdocument` variable with `cfprint`. The printing works but it takes a lot of time before running.
Please, what can be the cause.

PS: I'm fetching some data from my database.

The code is nothing more than in this format

```
<cfquery datasource="xxx" name="fg">
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE 1 = 1
</cfquery>

<cfdocument name="print_pdf" format="pdf" localUrl="true">
    I did some little outputting of the query here e.g 

     <cfoutput query="fg">
        #column1#<br>
        #column2# * #column3#<br>

</cfdocument>

<cfprint source="print_pdf" printer="PRINTER NAME">
```

But when i load this page it takes while. really long before loading completely. Is there anything i'm doing wrong or any way to optimize the work?

Comment: Do you have debugging turned on?

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes, My debugging is turned on.

Comment: How long does the query take to execute and how many records does it return?

Comment: After the `<cfquery>`, `<cfdocument>`, and `<cfprint>`, I would output the time. I would want to determine which is the slowest

Comment: If you are adding a lot of images in to the PDF, then that could be make the document creation slow.